Only run scenarios that match ALL tags using Godog
I'm using Godog to perform Cucumber tests in my Go API. My tests are defined in .feature files with scenarios tagged accordingly. I'm looking for a way to run scenarios based on tags, where scenarios are executed only if specific tags are fully matched. For example, consider the following scenarios:
@a
@b
Scenario: Scenario 1
   ...

@a
Scenario: Scenario 2
   ...

@a
@c
Scenario: Scenario 3
   ...

I want Scenario 3 to only be executed when BOTH a AND c are specified. Currently, if I specify a, it will run all scenarios.
I've attempted to implement this using the following Go code snippet (simplified):
func (m ScenarioManager) GetTags() string {
    tags := m.Environment
    if tag := GetTags(); tag != "" {
        tags += " && " + tag
    }
    return tags
}

func TestGenericScenario(t *testing.T) {
    env := GetEnvironment()
    apiConfig, err := suite.ParseConfigFile(GetEndpointConfigFilePath(), env)
    ...
    manager := ScenarioManager{Environment: env, ApiConfig: apiConfig}
    tests := godog.TestSuite{
        ScenarioInitializer: manager.InitializeScenario,
        Options: &godog.Options{
            ...
            Tags:        manager.GetTags(),
            Concurrency: 1,
        },
    }
    if tests.Run() != 0 {
        t.Fatal("non-zero status returned, failed to run feature tests")
    }
}


I thought that using the && operator would do the trick, but it's not.
Thank you.

How about using tags ab, a and ac instead?

This could work but it's really a hacky solution and doesn't work well in a big environment where there are potentially thousands of scenarios. Thanks for the suggestion though!
